# Devise get remote_ip in model validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to validate user sign ups against a Spam service that requires the IP and eMail. I'm using Rails 4.2 with Devise. Devise has the current_sign_in_ip attribute, but it is nil during sign up.

Is there a way to pass the value of request.remote_ip from the Devise registration/create controller action to the User model on sign up?

I tried the following, but the key is not added:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    sign_up_params[:current_sign_in_ip] = request.remote_ip
    super
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. The before_filter needed to be uncommented and the param added to the permit list.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]

  def create
    params[:user][:current_sign_in_ip] = request.remote_ip
    super
  end

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :current_sign_in_ip
  end

end
```